# wrapContentSize not working for ExposedDropdownMenuBox in jetpack compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dropdown, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a simple ExposedDropdown. I need to use wrapContentSize to fit to the size of the Text in the textfield. But its not working. The ExposedDropdown is only taking the default size.

PS: I do not want to set a constant width and height.

How to change size of ExposedDropdown

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun DropDownMenuExampleView() {
var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var gender by remember { mutableStateOf("male") }

ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(colorResource(id = R.color.accessBlue)),
    expanded = isExpanded,
    onExpandedChange = { newValue ->
        isExpanded = newValue
    }
) {

    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth().menuAnchor(),
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.johnstonBlack),
            fontFamily = FontFamilySingleton.johnson100FontFamily,
        ),
        value = gender,
        onValueChange = {},
        readOnly = true,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
            focusedContainerColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bakerloo),
            unfocusedContainerColor = colorResource(id = R.color.circle),
            disabledContainerColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bus),
            focusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.district),
        )
    )
    ExposedDropdownMenu(
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
        expanded = isExpanded,
        onDismissRequest = {
            isExpanded = false
        }
    ) {
        DropdownMenuItem(
            text = {
                Text(text = "Male")
            },
            onClick = {
                gender = "Male"
                isExpanded = false
            }
        )
        DropdownMenuItem(
            text = {
                Text(text = "Female")
            },
            onClick = {
                gender = "Female"
                isExpanded = false
            }
        )
        DropdownMenuItem(
            text = {
                Text(text = "Other")
            },
            onClick = {
                gender = "Other"
                isExpanded = false
            }
        )
    }
}
```

}